# JavaScript blocks other scripts on the page

Tags: javascript, block

I have a few JavaScript files which I have embedded in a Django app page.  They work without any problems independently, but one script blocks the rest from running properly wherever I include it.

The errors I get are:

```
jquery.min.js:19 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetWidth' 
of null

main.js:39 body.scrollTop is deprecated in strict mode. Please 
use 'documentElement.scrollTop' if in strict mode and 'body.scrollTop' 
only if in quirks mode.

jquery.min.js:4 body.scrollLeft is deprecated 
in strict mode. Please use 'documentElement.scrollLeft' if in strict 
mode
```

Here are all of my script imports:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAcCsb4_1FhEOP4bYPwm10FV_bGhjHBBH0&sensor=true"></script>
<script src="{% static "scripts/map-canvas.js" %}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="{% static "scripts/buzz.min.js" %}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static "scripts/syncSound.js" %}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static "build/js/storyjs-embed.js" %}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static "scripts/tl.js" %}"></script>
```

The storyjs-embed script could be the problem. It is from an open source product, the KnightLab TimelineJS - https://github.com/NUKnightLab/TimelineJS . [This](https://github.com/NUKnightLab/TimelineJS/blob/master/build/js/storyjs-embed.js) is the link to the troublesome script.

Could it be that it is not formatted properly?  What causes this error?

Comment: Open up your console and tell us if there are any javascript errors.

Comment: GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/styles/map-styles.css 404 (NOT FOUND) 127.0.0.1/:18
 GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/webapp/getUserRecs:pyordanov 500 (INTERNAL SERVER ERROR) jquery.min.js:19
 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetWidth' of null main.js:39
 body.scrollTop is deprecated in strict mode. Please use 'documentElement.scrollTop' if in strict mode and 'body.scrollTop' only if in quirks mode. jquery.min.js:4
 body.scrollLeft is deprecated in strict mode. Please use 'documentElement.scrollLeft' if in strict mode and ..



I see some warnings and errors which I will fix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have imported scripts that rely on two different versions of jquery.  You have a few options:

1. Rollback your imported version of jquery to something older until it starts working.
2. Take the script that needs the older version of jquery in order to work and find a replacement, so getting rid of the buggy software.
3. Rewrite the code under the hood to not use deprecated javascript/jquery methods.
4. It seems to be saying that strict mode is preventing something from working, try removing strict mode.